# Shiny failed to start

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I had an application in my shiny-server working fine some months ago. Today I returned to it and got the most curious error. Whenever I try to access it, I just get this massage

```
An error has occurred

The application failed to start.

The application exited during initialization.
```

Now the natural step would be to go check the log of this error, right? But the Logs created by this error are just empty, 0 bytes. So I am really puzzled why this is happening, I also tried to run the shiny sample apps and get the same error, but the server itself seems to be running just fine.

I know this is sort of a vague question, but honestly I don't know what other info could I put here due to the empty logs and it could be that someone came across a similar issue

Comment: You may just need to restart your app using `start shiny-server`.

Answer (score 0):

Shiny Server defaults to sanitised error logs, which is not useful in this case. You can change this behaviour by adding the line `sanitize_errors off;` to `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`. You may need to restart Shiny Server to see the effect.

To open `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
```

To restart Shiny Server:

```
sudo restart shiny-server
```

This should give you the verbose error messages you want.